# Mail not sending on macOS

Tags: mail.app, bug

Suddenly my Mail client on macOS doesn't send new mail (on any account). I can use the send UI as normal, but no mail is sent, none is recorded in Sent Mail, and I get no feedback or warnings that anything is amiss. It just vanishes.

I can *reply* to and *forward* mail using macOS Mail without issue (as near as I can tell), and I have no issues with Mail (for all the same accounts) on iOS (or of course with any of their web interfaces).

Comment: "You can use the send UI as normal.."  Does that mean you can use the mail provider's webmail interface?  Are these common providers like Gmail, Outlook, or Yahoo? Or is it a different provider?

Comment: From the Mail menu bar, select Window > Connection Doctor. Do you see a green dot next to each of your mail accounts?

Comment: @Allen I mean I can use the Mail app to send without any issues: compose, press send, etc.

Comment: @LincD. All green

Comment: @Allan  I'm connected to multiple providers (same list as on my phone: Apple, Gmail, Exchange, Outlook, etc.). No issues with any with the Mail client on my phone (or obviously with their webmail interfaces). And no issues replying (it seems), just with _new_ mail, for all services.

Comment: Check your default "From" address.  When you send, are you using a domain specific to that mail provider?

Comment: @Allan I've tried all the from fields. I just use the same "From" list I've always used: the list that appears in the compose UI, the same list that appears when I forward or  reply.

Comment: No, check that you're using your gmail address with gmail only.  If you try to send an Apple mail with a Gmail "from", it'll fail.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug with macOS 13.5 that is (partially) fixed in 13.5.1.

Comment: 13.5.1 seems to mostly fix it. All accounts except iCloud work, but iCloud mail without anything in the mail body (a common quick test unfortunately) still doesn't work.

Comment: This is a known bug according to...?

Comment: @MarcWilson Apple, of course. Thanks for asking.

Comment: I thought it would have been obvious, but claims like that require documentation.